# adding columns to header in mpxj using ProjectWriter

Tags: mpxj

I am trying to write an xml file using ProjectWriter in mpxj library.

I am able to write the data but I would like to create some custom fields also along with writing the data.

Can you please suggest how to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't "create" custom fields in MS Project *per se*, but you can provide an alias for one of the built in custom fields on tasks, resources, or assignments:

```
  ProjectFile file = new ProjectFile();
  file.setTaskFieldAlias(TaskField.TEXT1, "My New Name");
```

When you add TEXT1 to a table showing task data, the column should be visible as "My New Name".

This is only supported when you are writing data to an MSPDI (XML) file.